# How to set the subnet of a network interface?

Tags: linux, fedora, subnets

For an assignment I'm setting up a router in Linux and I have to edit the p7p1 config file to set the network up. One thing I have to do is set the local subnet to 172.27.13.0/24. I'm assuming this isn't the same as the subnet mask, so what would I put in the configuration file to set this? If it's needed I'm using an older Fedora distro.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. The `172.27.13.0/24` tells us that you are using the `172.27.13.0` network, and the `/24` tells us your subnet mask is 24-bits. If you don't want to get much deeper into how subnet masks and networking at large work, you can reference a table like the one currently found on Wikipedia's [Subnetwork article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnet_and_host_counts) to convert from CIDR notation (with a slash and a number) to dotted-decimal notation (ie `255.255.255.0`).

Comment: Alright, so do I have to do anything for this other than do IPADDR=172.27.13.1 and NETMASK=255.255.255.0, or will that suffice?

Comment: If 172.27.13.1 is the IP address they want (it is a legitimate IP address in that subnet). That is the correct NETMASK= statement, and I don't think we can get any other useful information in this context from what was provided.

Comment: I think a better way to word what I'm asking would be "does using the ip address 172.27.13.1 automatically set the subnet to 172.27.13.0, or is there another line I have to use for setting the subnet?" Thanks by the way, you've been really helpful

Comment: The computer/server easily calculates the subnet from the IP address and subnet mask, so you don't specify the subnet (just the mask).

Comment: To be properly configured, an interface requires an address and subnet mask.  The combination is used to calculate the subnet (aka network address of the subnet).